# Nginx not proxying the website from port 1337

Tags: node.js, nginx

I am followed this tutorial(https://medium.com/@atishubh.vaishnaw/deploying-hosting-a-node-app-in-aws-ec2-instance-part-1-9b6afccc8be6)  step by step and adapted the code where it is needed , but nginx is not doing its job. It just shows the Welcome to nginx! Page. Here it is my inside of the config file form the path /etc/nginx/mywebsite.extension:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/carrating.ml/html;
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html
server_name carrating.ml www.carrating.ml;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337;#whatever port your app run
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I am running the web server on nodejs on port 1337

Comment: If you ssh to the host and run `curl http://localhost:1337`, does it return what your node app is supposed to serve?

Comment: Yes , I get the website when I curl http://localhost:1337

Answer (score 1):

Move the file from `/etc/nginx/mywebsite.extension` location to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/carrating.ml.conf`.

```
sudo mv /etc/nginx/mywebsite.extension /etc/nginx/sites-available/carrating.ml.conf
```

Then create a symbolic link to the file inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` directory using:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/carrating.ml.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Restart the nginx server:

```
# Test NGINX config
sudo nginx -t

# Restart NGINX
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: hi , it allready is in on that patch, but without the extension .config . Thanks for the idea and I'll try it as soon as possible

Comment: i tryed changing the extension from carrating.ml to carrating.ml.conf but it does the same think unfortunatley.